# String manipulation/parsing in PHP

Tags: php, string

I've a string in the following format:

```
John Bo <jboe@gmail.com>, abracadbra@gmail.com, <asking@gmail.com>...
```

How can I parse the above string in PHP and just get the email addresses? Is there an easy way to parse?

=Rajesh=

Comment: Is the string delimited in a consistent manner (commas), is it always names and email addresses?

Comment: Yes, the string is always delimited using "commas"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One-liner no loops!

```
$str = 'John Bo <jboe@gmail.com>, abracadbra@gmail.com, <asking@gmail.com>';

$extracted_emails = array_map( function($v){ return trim( end( explode( '<', $v ) ), '> ' ); }, explode( ',', $str ) );

print_r($extracted_emails);
```

requires PHP 5.3

Comment: Is a one liner really that impressive if at the cost of readability?

Comment: Well, i never said it was impressive...and honestly i find my solution more readable than yours. You have $items, then you overwrite $items, then you have $emails, and $item, and $matches. If statements, continues, multidimensional arrays, and regular expressions.   I think its pretty clear what my code does, check out the variable name =)

Comment: And i like to mess around with the new anonymous functions

Comment: Fair enough, I see your side of it :) Maybe I just understand things better reading it procedurally then from left to right trying to keep track of what has been returned where.

Comment: Thanks Galen - this worked fine (as well as others). I preferred your one-liner though - less and clean code :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could of course just use a regex on the string, but the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322) complaint regex is a monster of a thing.

It would also fail in the unlikely (but possible event) of `a@b.com <b@a.com>` (unless you really would want both extracted in that case).

```
$str = 'John Bo <jboe@gmail.com>, abracadbra@gmail.com, <asking@gmail.com>';
 
$items = explode(',', $str);
$items = array_map('trim', $items);
 
$emails = array();
 
foreach($items as $item) {
    preg_match_all('/<(.*?)>/', $item, $matches);
    
    if (empty($matches[1])) {
       $emails[] = $item;
       continue;
    }
    $emails[] = $matches[1][0];
}
 
var_dump($emails);
```

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/sF0CR).

#### Output

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(14) "jboe@gmail.com"
  [1]=>
  string(20) "abracadbra@gmail.com"
  [2]=>
  string(16) "asking@gmail.com"
}
```

Comment: Why does it need to be exploded first? Just wrap an email regex in a capturing group and collect the matches.

Comment: @Braeden Because matching emails with regex is a difficult task (if strictly following the [RFC spec](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5322)).

Comment: It's a long and tedious regex, but it will never fail because of a simple formatting difference. There IS a ginormous RFC-valid regex. But I suppose if he's guaranteeing the formatting, then this is fine.

Comment: @BraedenP Yep, I didn't want to include that monster here, so I went the opposite way and match the stuff between the `<` and `>`.

Answer (score 0):

The most straight-forward way would be to (also I am terrible at regex):

```
<?php

$emailstring = "John Bo <jboe@gmail.com>,<other@email.com>, abracadbra@gmail.com, <asking@gmail.com>";
$emails = explode(',',$emailstring);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($emails); $i++) {
    if (strpos($emails[$i], '<') !== false) {
        $emails[$i] = substr($emails[$i], strpos($emails[$i], '<')+1);
        $emails[$i] = str_replace('>','',$emails[$i]);
    }
    $emails[$i] = trim($emails[$i]);
}

print_r($emails);

?>
```

http://codepad.org/6lKkGBRM

Comment: but then there is a combination of Name and <email address> and I just need the email address.

Comment: how are the `name` and `email address` combination formatted?

Answer (score 0):

Use `int preg_match_all (string pattern, string subject, array matches, int flags)` which will search "subject" for all matches of the regex (perl format) pattern, fill the array "matches" will all matches of the rejex and return the number of matches.

See http://www.regular-expressions.info/php.html